# Some minor improvements to the Help Center

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

Poking around the site, I noticed this is our current help center text:

> Space Exploration is primarily about spacecraft, how to get them to space, and what they do when they get there. Specifically, questions about these are encouraged.
>
> - space exploration
> - Satellite Design and Operations
> - potential systems that could be used in space
> - Science discovered by space probes
>
> However, there are many topics which are not on topic, including:
>
> - Study of exosolar objects, except as they relate to space travel.
> - Physical Sciences, such as geology, astronomy, meteorology, except how they relate to spacecraft.

After applying minor grammar magic, it would be nice if we could change it to this (changes bolded):

> Space Exploration is primarily about spacecraft, how to **send** them to space, and **their functions** there. Specifically, questions **on these topics** are encouraged.
>
> - space exploration
> - satellite design and **operation**
> - **systems with potential use** in space
> - **scientific discoveries made** by space probes
>
> **Questions these topics (and many others) are *not* on topic here:**
>
> - **The** study of exosolar objects, except as they relate to space travel.
> - Physical **sciences**, such as geology, astronomy, meteorology, **except as they relate** to spacecraft **and space exploration**.

How's it look?

Comment: I am poor with grammar...;-)  But for a layman such as me it looks perfect..

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and made the changes, except I capitalized the first word in the first section, it just looks better like that. Thanks for the input!